# Show text when mouseover column header of ngx-datatable column in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, core-ui

I am absolutely new in Angular. I want to change the column header text when mouseover on it. Attached a snapshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq0OC.jpg) :

below is my code.

```
 <div *ngIf="configGridParameterVersionResult != null" fxLayout="column">
              <ngx-datatable [fxFlex]="configGridParameterVersionResult.gridHeight"
                  scrollbarV="true"
                  scrollbarH="true"
                  class="material selection-row" 
                  [columnMode]="'force'"
                  [headerHeight]="50"
                  [footerHeight]="50"
                  [rowHeight]="35"
                  [rows]="configGridParameterVersionResult.rows"
                  [selectionType]="'single'"
                  >
                  <ngx-datatable-column name="Equipment" [flexGrow]="1" resizable="false">
                    <ng-template let-value="value" >
                      <span>{{value}}</span>
                    </ng-template>
                  </ngx-datatable-column>
                  **<ngx-datatable-column name="*PDF*" [flexGrow]="1" [width]="60" resizable="false" [cellClass]="getCellClass">
                    <ng-template let-value="value">
                      <span>{{value}}</span>                          
                    </ng-template>
                  </ngx-datatable-column>**
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try mouseenter and mouseleave events.

```
(mouseenter)="<<change text>>"
(mouseleave)="<<change text back>>"
```

Use the `name="*PDF*"` part and bind a variable instead of a fix string:
`name="columnName"` and then you can reference it in the  event handlers too: `(mouseenter)="columnName="My Longer PDF text"` etc.

So you solution is something like this:

```
<ngx-datatable-column 
   [attr.name]="columnName" 
   [flexGrow]="1" 
   [width]="60" 
   (mouseenter)="columnName='hovering text here'"
   (mouseleave)="columnName='PDF'"
   resizable="false" 
   [cellClass]="getCellClass">
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. in which tag do I need to modify?
could you please help me to update my code roughly?

Comment: Can you explain or provide better code example. @ForestG

Comment: this is a 4 years old answer, I would reccomend this approach anymore. If you provide a new question and a stackblitz example I am happy to help your issue @Nicks